# Selenium ChromeDriver C# how to block video download and play

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to know how to use Selenium and ChromeDriver, or possibly Chrome itself, to block video on a page from downloading and playing. It consumes bandwidth and time while I am testing other functionality. I do not have direct control of the video web elements.

For example, here is a video that I would like to avoid playing:

```
<video src="http://content.myvid.com/some_video.mp4" autoplay="" preload="auto" class=" __foo_content_video"></video>
```

I am already using image blocker extension for Chrome. Which works great blocking static images from being downloaded and displayed. I wish that it did the same for videos but it doesn't.

My testing setup is using the following versions:

- Selenium 3.0.1
- ChromeDriver.2.29.0
- chrome32_58.0.3029.81

I am hoping that this is solved with a simple `ChromeOptions` argument or capability.

Comment: Can you share a sample url which plays video automatically?

Comment: @Dev: You can see in my example above that I obfuscated the mp4 file URL. I don't want to share my client's proprietary content. I suppose any mp4 will work. I don't have one handy.

Comment: @Dev: I found one with a google search, look here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

Comment: Where is the video in this page? - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

Comment: @Dev: click where it says "try it yourself"

Answer (score 0):

If it is HTML5, there is a browser extension called "Disable HTML5 Autoplay" in the chrome web store.  I've never used this and it has mixed reviews.

Another option would be to use an autoresponder in Fiddler.  Figure out what URL is being called for the video and autorespond with your desired content.  I did this when dealing with a page that had a huge file (PDF I think) that I didn't care about, so I setup an autoresponder to return a 404 message.  Unfortunately, I don't have that setup anymore so I can't share code / screenshots.

Comment: I saw that extension, too. It actually does stop the html5 video from playing - which is nice - but doesn't stop it from downloading. It's only half the solution. The autorespond idea has some merit, although it sounds like I would have to know the name of the mp4 URL for it to work. These pesky videos have different URL's most of the time.